# Javascript Events, Capturing works Bubbling doesn't

Tags: javascript, events

My understanding of JS event propagation is that an event first "captures" down the DOM tree, then "bubbles" back up, triggering handlers along the way.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="textbox">
        nothing yet
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    // Gets incremented by "update" event
    var val = 0;

    // Event starts here
    textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    textbox.addEventListener("update", function(e) {
        textbox.innerHTML = val;
    }, false);

    // Should bubble here
    body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.addEventListener("update", function(e) {
        val++;
    }, false); 

    function update() {
        var e = new Event("update");

        textbox.dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    setInterval(update, 10);
</script>
</html>
```

In my [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/py9vyr7h/) there is a div "textbox" inside the body. I think the update event sent to the textbox should bubble up to the body, but it doesn't. The counter never updates.

If I set the UseCapture argument of the body's event listener to true, the counter updates.

Why does capturing work, but not bubbling?

Comment: Try `console.log(e.bubbles)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dispatchEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-eventtarget-dispatchevent) [dispatches](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch) your event. [Summarizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events), that means

> When an [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event) is [dispatched](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch) to an object that
>   [participates](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-participate) in a [tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree) (e.g. an [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-element)), it can reach
>   [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) on that object's [ancestors](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-ancestor) too.
>
> First all object's [ancestor](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-ancestor) [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) whose
>   **capture** variable is set to true are invoked, in [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order).
>
> Second, object's own [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) are invoked.
>
> And finally, and only if [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event)'s [bubbles](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-bubbles) attribute value is
>   true, object's [ancestor](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-ancestor) [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) are invoked again,
>   but now in reverse [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order).

Therefore, if the `bubbles` attribute is not true, the event won't bubble.

You can set the `bubbles` attribute to true when you create the event with `Event`:

> ```
> event = new Event(type [, eventInitDict])
> ```
>
> Returns a new *event* whose [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-type) attribute value is set to
>   *type*. The optional *eventInitDict* argument allows for setting the [`bubbles`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-bubbles) and [`cancelable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-cancelable) attributes via object members
>   of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

To get the effect you want (show nothing yet, then 0,1,2,...) you need to follow a couple of the previous answers, plus set capturing on the textbox. (otherwise you'll see show nothing yet, 1, 2,...). First you need to set bubbling to true on your event - like this:

```
function update() {
    var e = new Event("update",{bubbles:true});
    textbox.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Then you need to capture the event (set to true) - like this:

```
// Event starts here
textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
textbox.addEventListener("update", function(e) {
    textbox.innerHTML = val;
}, true);
```

So everything looks like this:

```
// Event starts here
textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
textbox.addEventListener("update", function(e) {
    textbox.innerHTML = val;
}, true);

// Should bubble here
body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.addEventListener("update", function(e) {
    val++;
    console.log(val)
}, false);


function update() {
    var e = new Event("update",{bubbles:true});
    textbox.dispatchEvent(e);
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Comment: Setting `capture=true` for `textbox` has no effect, since it's at the "bottom" of the DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `{ bubbles: true }` as the second argument to `new Event( ... )` for the Event to bubble, as per [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event), because [`bubbles` defaults to `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#Values).

[Updated jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/py9vyr7h/2/)

Answer (score -1):

If you use the old (unfortunately deprecated) way, it does bubble. See https://jsfiddle.net/py9vyr7h/1/

```
function update() {
    var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    // Second param says to bubble the event
    event.initEvent('update', true, true);
    textbox.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```